# Como calcular valor de parcelas com juros?

Tags: javascript, matemática

Preciso de ajuda para calcular valores com Juros para simulação de pagamento de boleto via PicPay

Segundo a pagina do PicPay,

> **Qual a taxa para pagar boletos?**
>   Confira as taxas para pagar contas como PicPay:
>
> Para pagar boletos com cartão de crédito: 2.99% sobre o
>   valor do pagamento via cartão;
>
> Para parcelar boletos: 2.99% sobre o valor do boleto + 3.49% sobre
>   cada parcela;

Porém ao fazer os calculos eu não estou conseguindo achar o valor que ele me da no app

```js
var jurosPorBoleto = 2.99;
var calculado = false;
var jurosPorParcela = 0.0349;

function gerarParcelas(){
if (calculado) {
    window.location.reload(true);
}
    calculado = true;
    
    let valor = parseFloat(document.getElementById("valor-total").value);
    if(valor == null){
        return 0;
    }
    console.log(valor);
    
    valor += valor*(jurosPorBoleto/100) ;
    console.log(valor);
    

    for (let parcela = 1.00; parcela <= 12; parcela++) {

        if (parcela == 1) {
           var  valorParceladoComJuros = valor;
           var valorTotalComJuros = valor;
        } else {
            var montante = valor * Math.pow((1 + jurosPorParcela), parcela);
            var valorParceladoComJuros = montante / parcela;
            var valorTotalComJuros = montante;
        }
        
                
        
        var node = document.createElement("li");
        node.setAttribute("class",  "list-group-item ")
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(parcela + "\tx \t" + parseFloat(valorParceladoComJuros).toFixed(2) +"\tTotal de R$" + parseFloat(valorTotalComJuros).toFixed(2));
            
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        document.getElementById("parcelas").appendChild(node);        
    }  
    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Calculadora de boletos - PicPay</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="formulario">
      
        <img class="mb-4" src="./assets/Camada 2.png" alt="" width="90" height="90">
        <div class="input form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="valor-total" placeholder="Valor" value="1000" required>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick="gerarParcelas()">Gerar Parcelas</button>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <ul id="parcelas" class="list-group list-group-flush">

            </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

 
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se está usando `float` para valor monetário já está errado aí, pode ser que tenha outros, mas a pergunta não é muito específica. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101

Comment: como seria a melhor forma para valores monetários? sempre aprendi a tratar como Float.
Eu to precisando de uma formula para calcular os valores de uma parcela de modo que fique do mesmo jeito do PicPay, porém usei a formula de juros compostos e não estou conseguindo o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Passei um link para você ler. E aí você pode pesquisar mais aqui no site mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fórmula para o cálculo dos juros é pela [metodologia do financiamento com prestações fixas](https://www3.bcb.gov.br/CALCIDADAO/publico/exibirMetodologiaFinanciamentoPrestacoesFixas.do?method=exibirMetodologiaFinanciamentoPrestacoesFixas).

No seu caso, o cálculo fica assim:

```js
var calculado = false;
var jurosPorBoleto = 0.0299;
var jurosPorParcela = 0.0349;

function gerarParcelas() {
  if (calculado) {
    window.location.reload(true);
  }

  calculado = true;

  let valor = parseFloat(document.getElementById("valor-total").value);

  if (valor == null) {
    return 0;
  }

  console.log(valor);
  valor += valor * jurosPorBoleto;
  console.log(valor);

  for (let parcela = 1; parcela <= 12; parcela++) {
    if (parcela == 1) {
      var valorParceladoComJuros = valor;
      var valorTotalComJuros = valor;
    } else {
      var valorParceladoComJuros = valor * jurosPorParcela / (1 - Math.pow(1 + jurosPorParcela, -parcela));
      var valorTotalComJuros = valorParceladoComJuros * parcela;
    }

    var node = document.createElement("li");
    node.setAttribute("class", "list-group-item ");

    var textnode = document.createTextNode(
      parcela +
        "\tx \t" +
        parseFloat(valorParceladoComJuros).toFixed(2) +
        "\tTotal de R$" +
        parseFloat(valorTotalComJuros).toFixed(2)
    );

    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("parcelas").appendChild(node);
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Calculadora de boletos - PicPay</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="formulario">

    <img class="mb-4" src="./assets/Camada 2.png" alt="" width="90" height="90">
    <div class="input form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="number" id="valor-total" placeholder="Valor" value="1000" required>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick="gerarParcelas()">Gerar Parcelas</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <ul id="parcelas" class="list-group list-group-flush">

      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sei que é antigo mas esse cálculo aqui serviu pra mim:

```
calcFixedInstallmentWithMonthlyFee(installments, fee, total_value){
        //https://www3.bcb.gov.br/CALCIDADAO/publico/calcularFinanciamentoPrestacoesFixas.do
        //https://www3.bcb.gov.br/CALCIDADAO/publico/exibirMetodologiaFinanciamentoPrestacoesFixas.do?method=exibirMetodologiaFinanciamentoPrestacoesFixas
        
        
        let valorFinanciado = total_value,
        parcelas = installments,
        juros = fee, //ao mês
        cf = juros/(1 - (1 / Math.pow(1 + juros, parcelas))),
        valorDaParcela = cf * valorFinanciado;

        return valorDaParcela
    }

console.log(calcFixedInstallmentWithMonthlyFee(12, 0.0299, 3111.73))
```

[Print do cálculo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reUxP.png)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).